# Ionic4 Ion-select style property not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to apply css property for my alert Controller but not working.

> **home.html**

```
   <ion-select [(ngModel)]="accountSystem" placeholder="Match Accounting  Standard"  okText="Done" cancelText="Cancel"   class="select-account">
                  <ion-select-option value="PRC Gaap">PRC Gaap</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="IFRS">IFRS</ion-select-option>
                  <ion-select-option value="US Gaap">US Gaap</ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>
```

**global.scss**

```
   .select-account{
.alert-wrapper{
    .alert-button-inner{
    color:rgb(239,52,52);
    }
    .alert-button{
    color:rgb(52,223,57);
    }
}}
```

Comment: what do you actually want to give select css or alert box css ? If you want to alert box css then i have shared my solution below check it

Answer (score 1):

this is my working solution in my project.

**home.ts**

```
const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: "Alert",
      mode: "ios",
      cssClass: "codealert",
          buttons: [
       {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'alertbutton',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Ok',
          cssClass: 'alertbutton',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Ok');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

**global.scss**

```
.codealert {
  --background: white;
}
.alertbutton {
  color: #600001 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```